# How to use C# class in Angular project in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio-2017

I built Angular webSite on visual studio 2017:
Created ASP.NET Web Application and added a reference to Angularjs (package 1.6.5). actually, I created exactly the same application as shown on this link: http://angularfirst.com/your-first-angular-project-in-visual-studio/

The question is how to use c# class or c# library inside this application?
To clarify the question, how do I use instances of c# class or call methods of the class? Properties? Maybe I can bind it somehow? How to do this?
Thank you in advance, Julia :-)

Comment: C# is compiled and runs on the server, the Angular Java Script runs on client i.e. in the browser. They talk to each other using HTTP. You write some C# that will return JSON in response to a request and you consume this in the Angular code, on the client.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any reference?

Comment: I recommend taking a read through this for more information on how these technologies (ASP.NET and browsers) work together https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-vsc